# Null linear regression model in vowpal wabbit

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I would like to run a linear regression on vowpal wabbit using the null model (intercept only - for comparison reasons). Which optimizer should I use for this? Also is the best constant loss reported that of the simple average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1: For linear regression, if you care about averages, you should use `--loss_function squared` (which is the default).  If you care more about the median rather than the average (e.g. if you have some outliers that may greatly mess-up the average), use `--loss_function quantile`. BTW: these are not optimizers, just loss functions. I would leave the optimizer (enhanced SGD) as is (the default) since it works very well.

A2: `best constant` is the constant prediction that would give the lowest error, and `best constant loss` is the average error for always predicting that `best constant` number. It is the weighted average of all your target-variables. This is not the same as the intercept `b` in the linear-regression formula `y = Ai*xi + B`. `B` is the free term, independent of the inputs. `B` is not necessarily the average of the `y`s.

A3: If you want to find the intercept of your model, look for the weight named `Constant` in your model. This would require two short steps:

```
# 1) Train your model from the dataset
#    and save the model in human-readable (aka "inverted hash") format
vw --invert_hash model.ih your_dataset

# 2) Search for the free/intercept term in the readable model 
grep '^Constant:' model.ih
```

The output of the `grep` step should be something like:

```
Constant:116060:-1.085126
```

Where `116060` is the hash-slot (location in the model) and `-1.085126` is the value of the intercept (assuming no hash collisions, and a linear combination of the inputs.)

Comment: Thank you, so how do I translate a model that performs worse in terms of loss compared to the best constant? What is the value of the information of best constant's loss?

Comment: Sorry, unclear what you're asking: what do you mean by 'translate' a model?  "Performs worse" on what data?  Bad performance most common causes are bad-data or over-fitting but you didn't give any details on how you train? On what kind and size of data (# of examples, # of features, progress output)? what options have you used in training? How did you evaluate after training?... So really hard to help here. Best constant loss is useful to get a sense of the (weighted) average of your labels.

Comment: I had to be more concrete. So, in my case the model's loss is much worse than the best constant even if the RMSE is better than a simple average. I am working with high-dimensional categorical features and numerical output. The data size is small (in the order of 500-1000) and the number of features is large (in the order of 10K after OHE). What is the weighted average of labels? In my case, I have a simple regression problem (no weights), does this mean that best constant's loss is the average's loss?